# How to update Android and iOS MAUI app version via Azure DevOps build script

Tags: azure-devops, maui

I have a MAUI application with Android and iOS projects. When I build this application using Azure DevOps script I would like to automatically change application version.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MAUI app .csproj file, add the following directives:

```xml
<Target Name="UpdateAndroidAppVersion">
   <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionCode" Value="$(VersionCode)" />
   <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionName" Value="$(VersionNumber).$(BuildNumber)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="UpdateIOSAppVersion">
   <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Platforms/iOS/Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleVersion']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(BuildNumber)" />
   <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Platforms/iOS/Info.plist" Query="//dict/key[. = 'CFBundleShortVersionString']/following-sibling::string[1]" Value="$(VersionNumber).$(BuildNumber)" />
</Target>
```

In your azure-pipelines.yml script, at the top level, declare variables, to control version representation (particular variable values are shown just for example):

```yaml
variables:
  - name: versionNumber 
    value: "2023.1"
  - name: buildNumber
    value: $[counter(variables['versionNumber'], 0)]
  - name: versionCode
    value: $[counter('versionCode', 1)]
```

Then, in your yml-script, separately for android and ios jobs, declare the following MSBuild directives:

Android job directive:

```yaml
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: "Update Android App Version"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/MyMAUIApplication.csproj' 
    msbuildArguments: '/t:UpdateAndroidAppVersion /p:VersionNumber="$(versionNumber)" /p:VersionCode="$(versionCode)" /p:BuildNumber="$(buildNumber)"'
```

iOS job directive:

```yaml
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: "Update iOS App Version"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/MyMAUIApplication.csproj' 
    msbuildArguments: '/t:UpdateIOSAppVersion /p:VersionNumber="$(versionNumber)" /p:VersionCode="$(versionCode)" /p:BuildNumber="$(buildNumber)"'
```

Comment: what would be the output of this? It looks like that this pipeline will produce same version number every time.

Comment: It will produce version numbers like `2023.1.1.2` and so on. Note the `counter` declaration at the top of my post. It evaluates a number that is incremented with each run of a pipeline. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops